# ¿Cómo redireccionar tráfico de un subdominio a un puerto específico?

Tags: servidor, puertos, amazon, subdominio

Tengo una instancia de Ubuntu en Amazon Ec2, la cual tiene asignada una IP estática.

También tengo un dominio registrado, digamos `example.com`, al cual le he creado un subdominio, digamos `aplicacion.example.com`, que apunta a la IP pública de la instancia.

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo puedo hacer que el tráfico que se reciba por el subdominio solo se reciba en un puerto x, digamos 10000, de forma que a la susodicha aplicación solo se pueda acceder desde el subdominio aplicacion.example.com y no desde example.com?.

Tengo un registro DNS tipo A sobre `aplicacion.example.com`, que apunta a la IP de la instancia. De momento no poseo ningún servidor HTTP. Probablemente instale LAMP pero, independientemente de las páginas web, la idea es alojar varias webs/aplicaciones en la misma instancia con una sola IP pública y que cada subdominio apunte a alguno de esos proyectos en concreto.

Por ejemplo, si quisiera crear el subdominio `ssh.example.com` para conectarme a la instancia por SSH. Tal como lo tengo ahora, el resultado sería idéntico a conectarme por `example.com`, ya que apuntan a la misma IP, yo estoy buscando que redireccione el tráfico a `xxx.x.x.x:22`.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Qué servidor HTTP usas en tu instancia? ¿Las entradas DNS `aplicacion.example.com` y `example.com` apuntan a la IP de tu instancia? ¿Ambas páginas están alojadas en la misma instancia?

Comment: Hola, @OscarGarcia. Edité la pregunta para clarificar un poco más, espero sea de utilidad.

Comment: Es que la solución depende del servidor HTTP que vayas a usar, ya que apache, nginx, lighttpd, etc tienen su propia manera de llevar a cabo lo que deseas. Claro está, asumo que no vas a usar ELB de amazon, en cuyo caso también habría que hacer cambios en la configuración del ELB. Por cierto, si rediriges el tráfico a `xxx.x.x.x:22` es probable que tengas que parar previamente el servidor `sshd`, perdiendo la capacidad de administración remota a través de SSH (a no ser que, a su vez, cambies el puerto del servidor SSH). Por ahora veo mucho lío innecesario en tu arquitectura.

Comment: Bueno, acabo de editar tu pregunta para ver si así entendía un poco mejor lo que quieres hacer. Por lo pronto veo que estás un poco perdido en administración de sistemas, ya que un cliente de SSH siempre va a conectarse a través del puerto 22 a menos que se le indique lo contrario, por lo que la resolución DNS de `ssh.example.com` a la IP estática es suficiente para hacer lo que deseas, pero vas a conseguir lo mismo con cualquier DNS que apunte a la misma IP fija, como `aplicacion.example.com`. En el servicio SSH no existe el concepto de "equipos virtuaes" (virtual hosts) como en HTTP.

Comment: Por otro lado, si ninguna configuración en el lado del servidor HTTP (ya sea apache, nginx, lighttpd, iis, etc), sea cual sea el dominio DNS que uses para ello (`http://aplicacion.example.com`, `http://ssh.example.com`, `http://IP_estática`, etc) vas a ver la misma página web por defecto. Para que puedas publicar páginas diferentes por cada entrada DNS debes configurar la capacidad de virtual hosts de cada uno de ellos para que vaya a buscar los archivos de cada sitio web a una ruta diferente.

Comment: Por otro lado, no puedes forzar de antemano que vayan a un puerto determinado. Lo único que podrías hacer es que se redirija al puerto adecuado en caso de acceder al puerto por defecto (el 80 o 443) a través de una redirección HTTP, HTML y/o javascript. Y, por último, no debes olvidar configurar al servidor HTTP para que acepte peticiones por dicho puerto.

Comment: Hola, @OscarGarcia. Gracias por tus respuestas. Efectivamente, soy bastante principiante en la administración de sistemas, mas que nada por eso me decidí a montar la instancia, aprovechando la capa gratuita de Amazon para experimentar y aprender cosas. Entonces, por lo que entiendo, si el tráfico es HTTP, sí se pueden crear hosts virtuales a través de Apache o el servidor que utilice, pero si el tráfico es TCP, por ejemplo, no se pueden crear hosts virtuales para que se pueda acceder a través de un subdominio?

Comment: Exacto. El soporte de equipos o hosts virtuales debe implementarse a nivel de aplicación, siendo el cliente el que facilita la información de éste al servidor (en HTTP mediante la [cabecera `Host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host)). En el caso de SSH, el cliente realiza la resolución DNS, se conecta a la IP resuelta sin informar al servidor de cuál se usó para ello. En cuanto a los puertos, cada protocolo tiene el suyo estándar y si quieres usar otro diferente has de indicarlo antes de conectarte. En HTTP el puerto se indica en la URL y en SSH como parámetro.